# filters and custom Js with Laravel Backpack InlineCreate

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

i'm using InlineCreate on a project that uses filters on the list view and some custom Js to hide/modify some form fields in the create/update form.

The problem is that using filters throws an error and displays the full page (not only the create form) and no js code from my custom js is loaded.

The filters are in the function setup. screenshot below:
[image]

but i'm using a single filter so the problem is with the filters in general.

I'm loading custom js in the Create Operation like this: Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/clients.js');

Answer (score 0):

Hello @saycookie can you share details about problem to replicate it:

- Screenshot of error
- Output of `php artisan backpack:version`
- Share details of JS script

Thanks

Comment: λ php artisan backpack:version
### PHP VERSION:
PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:05:49) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
 
### LARAVEL VERSION:
10.32.1.0

### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:
backpack/activity-log: 2.0.0
backpack/basset: 1.2.1
backpack/crud: 6.3.0
backpack/devtools: 3.0.1
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.2
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/logmanager: v5.0.1
backpack/pro: 2.0.18
backpack/revise-operation: 2.0.0
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.1.1

Comment: I've added a screenshot in the original post. Js script is just hiding a field based on another field value (really basic)

Comment: Can you share with me a github repo with this example, because i cant replicate on my side, i see there is a message about "You cant have two filters with the same name" but i have not enough information on my side. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/alin09ro/example

Comment: the most important issue is the js code that doesn't load in the modal. the filters are not really mandatory but would be nice to have them working.

Comment: Hello @saycookie if you check our documentation (https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operation-inline-create#using-widgets-with-inline-create), when you want a script execute on inline the correct way is:

Widget::add()->type('script')->inline()->content('assets/js/clienti_arca.js');